# WrapText- Auto format cell height

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXML to create reports, I am filling data in existing excel template file.

In excel template 'Wrap text' for all cells is set to true. When my report is complete I open excel file.

In opened file cells are not sized correctly with text wrapping (text wrapping is not applied). Also I observed on machine with office 2007 it works cell are wrapped but on office 2013 cell are not correctly wrapped. If I just double click on any cell then entire row is correctly updated.

Can someone please help me in this, is any property \tag I can set in openXML so that on document open cells are correctly shown.

Previously we were using OLE office interface there it works always so expectation is it should work with openXML too.

Thanks,

Dhanaj

Comment: What you could try is to create a very simple Excel file using your tool. Open it, double-click as you describe then save it to a different file name (so that you have both files that differ only by the double-click). Now open the first file in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and use the Compare feature to see how the two files differ. The Tool will show you the differing Open XML *and* the code necessary to generate the second file from the first.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I tried that I see excel writes height for rows and some other information header information is changed. Finally after I found that below openSetting defined during file open solves my issue,<br/>                                                      OpenSettings settings = new OpenSettings();<br/>
settings.MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings = new MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings(MarkupCompatibilityProcessMode.ProcessLoadedPartsOnly, FileFormatVersions.Office2013); I want to fully understand what MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings actually does.

Comment: Did you try searching it? There's lots of useful information, right at the top, when I Google `MarkupCompatibilityProcessSettings`...